# Id column based on other columns

Tags: t-sql

I have a simple database with 2000 rows

```
create table [TableName](
    [variable1] [varchar](50) not null,
    [state] [varchar](50) not null, 
    [date] [date] not null
)
```

That look like this

```
[variable1] [state] [date]
 A           UT      2015-01-01
 A           UT      2015-01-02
 B           UT      2015-01-02
 B           UT      2015-01-02
 A           TX      2015-01-01
 C           TX      2015-01-01
...
```

I want to add and identity column that would be based on `variable1` and `state` so the table would look like this

```
[MyID] [variable1] [state] [date]
 1      A           UT      2015-01-01
 1      A           UT      2015-01-02
 2      B           UT      2015-01-02
 2      B           UT      2015-01-02
 3      A           TX      2015-01-01
 4      C           TX      2015-01-01
 ...
```

`add [MyID] [int] identity(1,1) not null` doesn't work, since it just gives each row a unique id. 
I want each distinct value in `variable1` column to have a unique id, but I want to also use `state` column incase several states have same value

Comment: Hi, So if the next row was `A, UT` would that have a `MyID` of 1 or 5?

Comment: @JamesAnderson it would be 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update this new column with dense_rank()

```
-- test data
select * into #t
 from (values
 ('A','UT',0),      
 ('A','UT',0),      
 ('B','UT',0),      
 ('B','UT',0),      
 ('A','TX',0),      
 ('C ','TX',0) ) x([variable1], [state], tkey) 
; 
-- update
with tdr as (
    select * , r=dense_rank() over( order by [variable1], [state])
    from #t
    )
update tdr set tkey = r;

select * from #t
order by [variable1], [state];
```

Comment: That works, but if I upload new rows with new values I have to do it again, and it would change the previously assigned rank

Comment: Can I set it up to run automatically,  as a unique id? And even if I upload new rows it wouldn't change rank on old rows?

Comment: Basically what you say means  X([variable1], [state]) is a separate entity So you then need to  break initial table into 2 tables, and  create a FK.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545571/how-do-i-make-a-composite-key-with-sql-server-management-studio

It sounds like what you are wanting is a composite key.  There is a T-SQL example in the link provided.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think it would create a unique column, just a key that would be stored as a constraint